# How to set environment variables to path so it can be read from GUI and command line from the same program?

Tags: bash, environment-variables, path, emacs, bashrc

I installed texlive and I want to add it as an environment variable to my Path so that Emacs AucTeX can read it when I start emacs from the GUI or from the command line. So far I've read that emacs only reads files from ~/.profile

Therefore my plan is to add texlive to my path in .profile to enable emacs GUI to read it and then source ~/profile from .bashrc in order for emacs that is started inside my non-login interactive Gnome terminal to see the path.

Note: I do not have a .profile file in my home directory. Only in my etc directory and I rather not touch that one, but I have a .bash_profile in my home directory. However I read that .bash_profile is only run for an interactive login session aka *console mode* which I don't use.

#### My plan is to create a .profile file in my home directory and do the following:

step 1: Create ~/.profile

Step 2: Add texlive environment variable to path in .profile

```
export PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2018/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH
export MANPATH=/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/doc/man:$MANPATH
export INFOPATH=/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/doc/info:$INFOPATH
```

Step 3: Source .profile from .bashrc

```
#Adding this at the bottom or start of .bashrc to source .profile when the terminal is opened.

if [-s ~/.profile]; then;
    source ~/.profile;
fi
```

I know that there is a lot of apprehension towards sourcing .profile from .bashrc due to the risk of causing an infinte loop. However since I am creating a .profile file from scratch this will not be a problem as it will not contain any code that references .bashrc.

#### My Questions:

1. What do you think of my plan?
2. Do you think it will work?
3. Do you have any suggestions on how to improve it or perhaps other alternatives

*Additional info*: My .bashrc only contains code that sources `~/etc/bashrc` and one environment variable that was automatically added by Anaconda: `export PATH="/home/Fedora_User/Anaconda3/bin:$PATH"`

Keep in mind that I know the gnome-terminal can be run as an interactive login shell but I have never done this and dont know if it will impact the performance of my terminal sessions.

Comment: emacs isn't going to read `~/.profile`, it reads `~/.emacs`  which contains elisp. Do you mean programs started from within emacs, such as `shell`, might read `~/.profile`?

Comment: I remember reading that emacs reads .profile [https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/37291/19261 ]. Or let me rephrase it: To find environment variables emacs reads .profile. This is why this exists: [Github](https://github.com/purcell/exec-path-from-shell). Additionally, AucTeX in emacs will need to read .profile

Comment: emacs does not read `.profile`, but if it is executed from a shell that has read the profile and has exported an env variable, then it will "know" the variable because it inherits the environment of the invoking shell. This is *NOT* specific to emacs: any program that is started by such a shell wil inherit the environment, so if it chooses it can find out the value of the env variable.

Comment: If you have an OS using `systemd` (>=233) you could consider this "future proofed" [suggestion](https://wiki.gnome.org/Initiatives/Wayland/SessionStart) of putting assignments in files like `~/.config/environment.d/my.conf`. It is not specific to Wayland, though that is the motivation.

Comment: @meuh I just checked and yes I have systemd version number 234. I'm not familiar with the .conf method of setting environment variables. Is this .conf file read by a non-interactive login shell thesame way as ~/.profile? And if I have ~/.profile and ~/.bash_profile how do I make the shell to read the .conf file? Also what are the advantages and disadvantages of using the .conf file compared to either ~/.profile or ~/.bash_profile.

Comment: I have not used this systemd feature, so I cannot be definite, but the [man page](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/environment.d.html) says the files set *the environment exported by the systemd user instance to the services it starts.* For you, the important question is, is your GUI started by systemd? I imagine the easiest way to find out is to put a new unique variable in such a file, logout and login and see if you find that variable in your environment for the cases that interest you.

Comment: Crossposting: https://askubuntu.com/q/1035262/336375

Comment: @meuh There is an interesting article that summarises environment.d and systemd here:(https://in.waw.pl/~zbyszek/blog/environmentd.html). My GUI is wayland and the command `man init` in terminal shows systemd so I believe its my default system manager. After looking through ~ it seems that I have a .config directory but environment.d does not exist.

Comment: @meuh I don't have the `environment.d` directory in the path `~/.config/environment.d/my.conf`. I know you can easily create a dot file like .conf from scratch but will doing thesame for a directory work?

Comment: Just create directory `~/.config/environment.d/` yourself. There is no reason it should already exist.

Comment: @meuh, Right. I already have the `.config directory`. I wasnt sure whether `environment.d` had to be created by systemd version >=233. I guess as long as the program has been configured to look there then it doesn't matter.